# Objective C Class instance properties deallocating in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, retain, reference-counting

Working on an iPhone app where I have a class instance that is defined as a global and initialized in in ViewDidLoad for a UITableViewController.

When it gets to cellForRowAtIndexPath, the instance properties are deallocated and appear as  in the debugger.

The properties are being loaded from the database.

**Foo.h**

```
NSString *prop1;

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *prop1;
-(void)shouldLoadProperties;
```

**Foo.m**

```
@synthesize prop1;

-(void)shouldLoadProperties {
    <FMDatabase stuff here>

    FMResultSet *rs = [self executeQuery:sql];
    prop1 = [rs stringForColumn:@"col1"];  //loads db value "Test" into prop1
}
```

The tableview controller:

**TestTableViewController.h**

```
Foo *foo;
```

**TestTableViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   foo = [[[Foo alloc] init] retain];
   [foo shouldLoadProperties];

   //Breakpoint here shows that foo.prop1 is set to "Test"

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //foo is is still allocated, but foo.prop1 has been 
   //deallocated;  shows as <freed object>  

  NSLog(@"Prop 1 is %@", foo.prop1);  //throws exception


}
```

I'm not releasing foo, so why would the properties deallocate themselves?  Am I missing something in Foo to hang onto the properties until the instance is released?

**UPDATE**

I found that by adding retain when populating the property from the database, that the data holds:

```
 prop1 = [[rs stringForColumn:@"col1"] retain];
```

Is this correct or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not using `prop1` as a property, but as a variable within your class.  You can and should give these different names.  It's customary to put an underline at the start of the variable name:

**foo.h**

```
NSString *_prop1;

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *prop1;
-(void)shouldLoadProperties;
```

**foo.m**

```
@synthesize prop1 = _prop1;
```

Now, to actually use your properties, use the getters and setters.  This will retain your value and release it when appropriate.

```
[self setProp1:[rs stringForColumn:@"col1"]];  //loads db value "Test" into prop1
```

and

```
self.prop1 = [rs stringForColumn:@"col1"];  //loads db value "Test" into prop1
```

are both valid and equivalent to each other.

```
_prop1 = [rs stringForColumn:@"col1"];  //loads db value "Test" into prop1
```

Will lead to crashing and other bad behavior.

Your update will prevent the crash, but will leak memory if you do it more than once.